# Large table partitioning in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-partitioning, large-data

There are two tables in a SQL Server 2000 database which have more than 50 million records, mostly have "read" rather than "write" or "delete". I want to redesign table.

Is creating a partitioning view on one server helping to improve speed? (does it have meaning to create partition in **one** server?)

Is creating a new file-group and putting this table on that (in one server) beneficial?

Except: re-indexing what are the other possible ways to improve speed for fetching data in such tables?

I goggled it lot, but not found anything else for 2000.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: First enable to execution plan and see your query having any table or index scans. If so then those should be addressed as result execution plan should show only index seek. Still it doesn't met the response expectation then look for partitioning.

Comment: "which have more than 50 million records" - that's not really that many. I have tables with 150 million rows and no partitioning and performance is good.

Comment: @MitchWheat : what's your opinion about my tables? maybe because they join to other tables , the speed is not acceptable.

Comment: @BhasyakaruluKottakota : in 99% times, users just read newer records(current year) , that's because I though of partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that partitioning (partitioned view or table partitioning) will improve performance in this scenario.  Index an query tuning that is the key to performance, which is even more important with large tables.  If you are having a performance problem, I suggest you post DDL and a sample problem query.

That begin said, partitioning can improve manageability.  For example, a partitioned view can allow to meet SLAs by reducing the time it takes for offline tasks, like an index rebuild of the current year data.  I would not expect that to be a pain point with only 50 million rows on modern hardware.

Segregating data on separate filegroups can improve performance in specialized cases, such as parallel scans of different years of data.  However, you mentioned that the current year data is queried 99% of the time so there might not be much benefit in your situation.

Comment: Guzman: thank for your complete comment. just one question, if the growing rate was high in this table(about 6 million records a year), is Indexing the best solution for optimization yet? and the other question is : In this table, there are several columns which are NULL in most cases , Is it a good idea if I want to separate the table and put these columns in second table related to base one?does it help for performance?

Comment: Indexing allows queries to touch the minimal pages for the task at hand regardless of whether the table is growing or not. That is the key to performance in an OLTP or mixed workload.  Adding another table may be best from a design perspective and will improve performance in cases where a join to that table is not needed.  But performance may be worse if you must all a LEFT JOIN to the existing queries.  There are sometimes trade-offs between a good normalized design and performance.